# Mac, /etc/paths not working as expected

Tags: macos, terminal

Here is the contents of my /etc/paths file

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

When using root this is the output of $PATH

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Shouldn't $PATH be built using the contents of /etc/paths?

Comment: Have you restarted bash?

Comment: Yes, plenty of times. Even rebooted.

Comment: and you opened the file as root?

Comment: I opened as root and my user.

Comment: alright. sorry then, i have no more ideas. your steps match up with what i found online. the only thing i can suggest is doing what i do, which is: $ export PATH=$PATH:/new/path/ and put that in a file bash loads at its startup. Unfortunately, I can't be more help than that

Comment: I'm resorting to restoring my machine to a previous date to when it worked. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Your $PATH seems to be overridden at some point. Try to log in as a different user (e.g. as a guest) and echo the variable.